# $f'(c) > 0$ implies increasing on $I$?

Tags: calculus

I already know that if $f'$ is positive on $I$ then $f$ is increasing on $I$.

But, I wanna know what if we know just $f'(c)>0$ where $c\in I$, not on whole $I$.

Then is there an open interval $I$ which contains $c$ such that $f$ is increasing on $I$?

I think there might be, but I can not prove why.

Since we know only the fact $f'(c)>0$, I can compare the value of function at $x$ with $c$.

But we have to compare all value at $x,y\in I$ to guarantee the increase.

How can I prove this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is $f$ is continuous on $I$?

Comment: If $f'$ is continuous, then what you say is true. Because then $f'(x) > 0$ on some open interval containing $c$ (assuming $c$ is in the interior of $I$)

Comment: As the question stands, the answer is no. You can take $f:]a,b]\to \Bbb R$ and then, if you take $c=b$, you won't find an open interval containing $c$ on which the function has this property because there is none.

Comment: @SalechAlhasov Does this thesis depend on continuity of $f$? If so, let me know why T-T

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan In this case, we do not have any information about $f'$.

Comment: @xavierm02 Sorry I missed $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Take for example $f(x)=x^3-3x^2+x$ on $(-1,1)$. It is easy to see that $f'(0)=1>0$. However, $f(1)=-1 < f(0)$, so $f$ cannot be increasing on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: If you have $f'$ continuous at $c$, then there is an open interval $(a,b)$ with $a<c<b$ so that $f'$ is positive on $(a,b)$ and $f$ is therefore increasing on $(a,b)$.

Comment: @AlexandreVandermonde As you read my question carefully, the point is the existence of such open interval. In your example, there is the possibility that $f$ is increasing on $I$, a subset of $(-1,1)$. And really there is.

Comment: @xavierm02 Again, we do not assume that $f'$ is continuous. Please tell me when $f'$ is NOT continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not assume continuity of $f'$ at $c$, this may not be true. For example, consider the function $f$ defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\frac{x}2 +x^2\sin\frac{1}x$ if $x\neq 0$. Then $f$ is $\mathcal C^1$ outside $0$ and easily seen to be differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)=\frac12>0$. However, $f$ cannot be increasing on any interval $(0,\delta)$. Indeed, if it were so we would have $f'(x)\geq 0$ on $(0,\delta)$. But if $x\neq 0$ then
$$f'(x)=\frac12+2x\sin\frac1x-\cos\frac1x\, ,$$
so $f'(x)\leq \frac12 +2x -\cos\frac1x $, and hence $f'(x)\leq \frac34-\cos\frac1x$ for all $x\in (0,\delta)$ if we assume (as we may) that $\delta\leq\frac18$. Since one can find $x>0$ arbitrarily close to $0$ such that $\cos\frac1x=1$, it follows that $f'$ cannot be $\geq 0$ on $(0,\delta)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think that my question would not be true. But, trigonometric function was the key!

Answer (score 2):

The function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} + \frac{x}{2} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{cases}$$
is differentiable everywhere.  Its derivative is
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}2x\sin\frac{1}{x} - \cos\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2} & x \neq 0 \\ \frac{1}{2} & x = 0\end{cases}$$
This derivative is not continuous.  We have $f'(0) > 0$ but because of the cosine term one can see that $f$ is not increasing on any interval that contains $0$.

Comment: Thanks :) but I couldn't set your answer to an accepted answer because Etienne posted little fast..T_T

Comment: It's funny that we gave exactly the same example!

Comment: I'm guessing you did the same thing I did, which is look up the standard example of a discontinuous derivative and then add the $\frac{x}{2}$ to get $> 0$ at the discontinuity :)

Comment: You're guessing right!